ITMS-91054: Invalid API category declaration
I added Privacy manifest for my app and submit it to review
and apple reject my app with what comment

ITMS-91054: Invalid API category declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy for the Frameworks/SmartlookAnalytics.framework/SmartlookAnalytics file contains Disk Space as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType key, which is invalid. Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType keys in any privacy manifest must be valid API categories. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit:
Describing use of required reason API - Swift Docs

i look at the package manifest and all looks fine (attached image).
Maybe somebody saw that issue - and may tell me how can i fix it.


The category listed in the error message and the category shown in your image are different. Are you sure you are checking the correct manifest?

Yep, into Info plist it's called as Disk Space, but in source code the name is - NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace

I don't know what the problem was, but smartlook has just published new version with this changelog:

Bumped to iOS SDK 2.2.11 with privacy manifest

So I think this will solve our problem

Xcode shows 'friendly' versions of the xcprivacy entries, just like it shows for Info.plist.
If you control-click in the data of the xcprivacy file, the context menu that pops up will contain a choice named "Raw Keys and Values".  If you click that choice, you will see what is really in the feel, and you should see the same keys and values as published in Apple's documentation.
If everything looks fine, then you might try making a new archive and generating the PDF privacy report. Then verify that report includes your framework and contains the correct values.  If they do contain correct values, then try submitting again.  Maybe something went wrong the process of submitting the previous version.

When it comes to any kind of plist files, it's always better to open file as source code and check all the key, values entered as per apple guidelines/documentation. In Plist mode, we usually select values from dropdown, which could not matched with apple standard keys. Example if I pick "Disk Space" from drop down and when I open file as source code, it should be "NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace".

Irrelevant, and just repeats an existing answer.
